# PHP/jQuery hyperlink text which begins with @

Tags: php

Can someone suggest the best way to go about this. I am retrieving the equivalent of a Tweets content from MySQL and echoing it out.

Sometimes the content contains a `@username` as part of the text. I need a way to hyperlink the `@username` part to `/username`.

E.g. if the PHP was:

```
$tweetcontent = 'Hey @alex how are you?';
echo $tweetcontent;
```

The content should become:

```
<body>Hey <a href="/alex">@alex</a> how are you?</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

Comment: Do you want a PHP or a JavaScript solution? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I was asking for advice in order to find the best way of doing it. That's why I included both tags. I apologise for not replying to your comment.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm removing my comment, which could have been nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the linkify function from here will help you

```
/**
* Turn all URLs in clickable links.
*
* @param string $value
* @param array $protocols http/https, ftp, mail, twitter
* @param array $attributes
* @param string $mode normal or all
* @return string
*/
    function linkify($value, $protocols = array('http', 'mail'), array $attributes = array(), $mode = 'normal')
    {
        // Link attributes
        $attr = '';
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $val) {
            $attr = ' ' . $key . '="' . htmlentities($val) . '"';
        }

        $links = array();

        // Extract existing links and tags
        $value = preg_replace_callback('~(<a .*?>.*?</a>|<.*?>)~i', function ($match) use (&$links) { return '<' . array_push($links, $match[1]) . '>'; }, $value);

        // Extract text links for each protocol
        foreach ((array)$protocols as $protocol) {
            switch ($protocol) {
                case 'http':
                case 'https': $value = preg_replace_callback($mode != 'all' ? '~(?:(https?)://([^\s<]+)|(www\.[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+))(?<![\.,:])~i' : '~([^\s<]+\.[^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~i', function ($match) use ($protocol, &$links, $attr) { if ($match[1]) $protocol = $match[1]; $link = $match[2] ?: $match[3]; return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="' . $protocol . '://' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value); break;
                case 'mail': $value = preg_replace_callback('~([^\s<]+?@[^\s<]+?\.[^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~', function ($match) use (&$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="mailto:' . $match[1] . '">' . $match[1] . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value); break;
                case 'twitter': $value = preg_replace_callback('~(?<!\w)[@#](\w++)~', function ($match) use (&$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="https://twitter.com/' . ($match[0][0] == '@' ? '' : 'search/%23') . $match[1] . '">' . $match[0] . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value); break;
                default: $value = preg_replace_callback($mode != 'all' ? '~' . preg_quote($protocol, '~') . '://([^\s<]+?)(?<![\.,:])~i' : '~([^\s<]+)(?<![\.,:])~i', function ($match) use ($protocol, &$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="' . $protocol . '://' . $match[1] . '">' . $match[1] . '</a>') . '>'; }, $value); break;
            }
        }

        // Insert all link
        return preg_replace_callback('/<(\d+)>/', function ($match) use (&$links) { return $links[$match[1] - 1]; }, $value);
    }
```

Reference from https://gist.github.com/jasny/2000705

Comment: Hi @Sasikumar sorry if it's obvious but how do I run and output a variable through that.

Comment: Figured it out. Just do `echo linkify("@username");` after the the function. Note though for anyone in future using this you have to add `'twitter'` to the `$protocols = array('http', 'mail')` part.

Comment: although @Sasikumar has given you a full solution but you can use only twitter case for yourself, like:
echo preg_replace_callback('~(?<!\w)[@#](\w++)~', function ($match) use (&$links, $attr) { return '<' . array_push($links, '<a' . $attr . ' href="https://twitter.com/' . ($match[0][0] == '@' ? '' : 'search/%23') . $match[1] . '">' . $match[0] . '</a>') . '>'; }, $userName);

Comment: @Ben that array is just the default value, if you called linkify like linkify("@adam look at this", array("http", "twitter")); it would change the array at runtime to only include http and twitter links

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a simple regular expression, Sasikumar's answer is a little bit overkill, and I think Jeff's answers is not ideal for your situation.

```
$string = 'Hey @alex, how are you? @user_123';

//find all string that start with @ and is followed by 
//any amount of lowercase and uppercase letters 
//as well as and underscore "_" and numbers 0-9
preg_match_all('/@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', $string, $matches);

//loop through all matches
foreach($matches[0] as $match)
{
    //get username without "@"
    $username = substr($match, 1);

    //create a link (note: $match is username with "@" sign
    $link = '<a href="/' . $username . '">' . $match . '</a>';

    //replace all matches with links
    $string = str_replace($match, $link, $string);   
}

//output for testing
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<?php
$str = "hi @google and @yahoo";
$regex = '/(@(\\w+))/i';// a simple regex additional validaton needs to be done by you

$sub = "<a href=\"$2\">$1</a>";
$result = preg_replace($regex , $sub , $str);

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: @Jeff if this answer worked for you please accept it as it may help other people

Comment: I didn't ask the question, it was better than my answer because it allowed multiple users, so I said it works good.